# How to add style property to the element having ng-class dynamically in angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-class

how to pass class:after using ng-class and how can u add property to existing css class
i have css as

```
<style>
customcss:after{
 border-top: 7px solid green;
}
</style>
```

i want to chage the color dynamically using ng-class or ng-style

i used as

```
<html>
    <div ng-class="{customcss: true}" ng-style="topcolor('yellow')"></div>
 </html>
<script>
 $scope.topcolor = function (color) {
                return '7px solid ' + color;
            }
</script>
enter code here
```

like above i had used, but the color is not changing dynamically

pleass help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML

```
<div class="customcss" ng-style="topcolor('yellow')"></div>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.topcolor = function(value) {
          return { "border-top": '7px solid ' + value};
      }
```

Try this one.

Comment: i want to add ::after also to class dynamically, atleast i want to update the exisiting property of the 'border-top'

Comment: @chaitanyak,it actually does the same. updating the border-top property dynamically. Did u check it out?

Comment: i tried, it is not working, i need how to use --  style="customcss:after{
 border-top: 7px solid green;
}"